# Two different types of OCaml recursive functions

Tags: recursion, ocaml, fold

During two weeks I've been doing some simple programs in OCaml. I've noticed that when we are working with a recursive structure `T` and we want to have the information `I` on `T`  then depending on the information `I` we have two types of recursive function.

For simplicity let's assume `T` is a binary tree. So I'll use the following type :

```
type 'a tree = Empty | 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

Now let's say the information `I` can be calculated from left to right on the binary tree. When I am saying left to right it means that the information `I` can be calculated from the root to the leaves without getting backward.

To be more clear let's say the information `I` we want to have is simply "the number of nodes of the binary tree". Then what's nice with this information is that when we get to all leaves then we get `I`, so we are going left to right in the sense that we begin from the root and expend recursively to the left and right subtree and the end case is when we arrived at the leaves.

So we simply have :

```
let rec nodes = function
    |Empty -> 0 (*it's ok we are done here*)
    |Node(_,l,r) -> 1 + nodes l + nodes r
```

What's very nice is that when the information can be calculated left to right then OCaml's pattern matching is a very strong tool and the information `I` can be calculated in an easy way.
So more generally we have :

```
let rec get_information = function
    | Empty     -> (*here we are done so we return a constant value*)
    |Node(_,l,r)-> (*here we apply recusrively the function to the left and right tree*)
```

Now here comes my problem. Let's say `I` is an information that can't be calculated from left to right but from right to left. So it means that to get the information `I` we need to begin from the leaves of the tree and extend recursively to the top and we are done only when we get to the root of the binary tree (so the end case is when we get to the root of the binary tree and not the leaves).

For example, let's say the information `I` is : "the binary tree has the propriety that for every node the number of nodes in his left subtree is strictly superior to the number of nodes in his right subtree". If we want to solve this in linear time then we need to begin from the leaves and expend recursively to the top (note that I don't necessarily want a solution to the problem).

So to me, it's tricky to write a function that gets the information `I` when `I` is a right to left information (it needs to begin from the leaves and extend to the top). On the contrary pattern-matching is perfect when the information is a left to right information.

So my question is how to do when we need to write a function that gets the information `I` (when `I` is right to left)? Are there techniques to solve these kind of problems? Is it still possible to use pattern matching in a tricky way in order to get the desired result?

Comment: Good observation! This is called [folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), and you're basically describing the difference between rightwards and leftwards folding, I think. I'll let someone more eloquent explain this in a proper answer, but have a look at the implementation of linear folding in the Wikipedia article to get an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Thank you! You are right this is what I am describing (I didn't know it has a name). I am going to read the Wikipedia article.

Comment: And actually, for lists, it's quite easy to implement a right folding but my question is about right folding for trees (and more general recurisve structures) which seems trickier (at least for me).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you find tricky about it? If you try to implement the example you gave, what problem(s) do you encounter that you're struggling to get past?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matching is useful for writing both kinds of function. Higher order functions called folds can also be used.

First, a concrete version. We will want to know whether a tree is left leaning, and if so, how many nodes it has. An `int option` will represent this nicely, with `None` indicating any non-left leaning tree.

```
type 'a tree = Empty | Branch of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree

let rec tree_info = function
  | Empty -> Some 0
  | Branch (_, l, r) ->
    match tree_info l, tree_info r with
    | Some x, Some y when x >= y -> Some (x + y + 1)
    | _ -> None

let is_left_leaning tree =
  match tree_info tree with
  | Some _ -> true
  | None -> false
```

(Note that the condition `x >= y` is not 'strictly greater than', but this is deliberate; `x > y` is a poor choice. I'll leave figuring out why as an exercise.)

We can also express this style of function in terms of an operation called a right fold. For this operation one provides a value for each constructor of the datatype being folded over: in each place that constructor occurs, the fold operation will use that value to compute the result of the fold:

```
let rec foldr empty branch = function
  | Empty -> empty
  | Branch (x, l, r) ->
    branch x (foldr empty branch l) (foldr empty branch r)
```

Note that the `empty` value and the `Empty` constructor have the same arity, and the `branch` value and the `Branch` constructor have the same arity, with corresponding argument types. That's characteristic of a right fold.

Given `foldr`, we can easily define `map`:

```
let map f tree =
  foldr Empty (fun x l r -> Branch (f x, l, r)) tree
```

Or of course, 'tree_info':

```
let tree_info tree =
  foldr
    (Some 0)
    (fun _ l r ->
       match l, r with
       | Some x, Some y when x >= y -> Some (x + y + 1)
       | _ -> None)
    tree
```

This is the alternative to pattern matching on the constructors of `tree`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I guess that you need `x>=y` because otherwise for every node of the tree you'll get the value `None`. Because with `x > y` we have : `tree_info Branch(_,Empty,Empty) = None`. So I think that your function answers the problem: "for every node of my tree the left subtree has more nodes (not necessarily strictly more) than the right subtree". I think that to get the answer to the problem: "...strictly..." we just need to add some pattern cases.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think that now I understood right folding on trees, do you think you can provide an exercise on a tree (like getting an information) to see if my understanding is good ? Thank you!

Comment: You are right about `>=`. Hmm, exercises for right folds... how about calculating the height of a tree? And second, a silly function `mirror` that swaps the left and right subtrees for every `Branch`.

Comment: Thank you! While thinking about your exercises I realized that we can't create a function fold_left for trees. This is due to the fact that a Node has multiple subtrees and hence we won't have a single result. Nevertheless, I think it's still possible to make such a fold_left function on binary-trees by adding an argument named `combine` which is a function that combined the values of the subtrees. So here is a possible implementation:

Comment: `let rec foldl empty branch combine = function |Empty -> empty |Branch(x,l,r) -> combine (foldl (branch empty Branch(x,l,r)) branch combine l) (foldl (branch empty Branch(x,l,r)) branch combine r)`

Comment: I think that the function `mirror` and the function `height` can be calculated without using right_folding. For example we can do the following for the function `mirror` : `let rec mirror = function |Empty -> Empty |Branch(x,l,r) -> Branch(x,mirror r, mirror l)`. So here it's a `left_folding`, hence it's possible to do the function `mirror` using the function `foldl` above such that `comibne` is defined as : `let combine x a b = Branch(x,b,a)`. We can also use `right_folding` but I think that it's always better to use left folding instead of right folding because left folding is tail recursive

Comment: It is quite reasonable to fold over the elements of a tree in the same way as `List.fold_left`, eg, `let rec foldl f acc = function Leaf -> acc | Branch (x, l, r) -> foldl f (f (foldl f acc l) x) r`. Of course for trees there is no single obvious order in which to visit the elements.